# Convert from object[] to double[] on C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, casting

I have a function that generates objects with different data in it (the function fills the object with random data, according to the type). The function returns an `object[]` as the type is only know at runtime (and it's passed to the function as a parameter).

```
double[] values;

values = factory.GetData(typeof(double), 10);
```

Unfortunately I get a compiler error:

> Cannot convert from object[] to double[].

How can I cast the `object[]` programmatically?

EDIT:

this is the original function:

```
    public object[] GetData(Type type, int howMany)
    {
        var data = new List<object>();

        for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            data.Add(Convert.ChangeType(GetRandom(type), type));
        }

        return data.ToArray();
    }
```

where `GetRandom()` create an object of type `type` and assign it a random value (random int, random string, random double, only basic types)

and this is the GetRandom() function:

```
   public T GetRandom<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            return prng.Next(0, int.MaxValue);
        }

        if (type == typeof(double))
        {
            return prng.NextDouble();
        }

        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            return GetString(MinStringLength, MaxStringLength);
        }

        if (type == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            var tmp = StartTime;
            StartTime += new TimeSpan(Interval * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
            return tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using generics?

Comment: no good reason, can you elaborate a little bit more please?

Comment: I would define `GetData` as: `public T[] GetData<T>(int count);` That way you would get the right type out of the method to begin with.

Comment: I tried but it says: "cannot convert expression type object[] to return type T[]"

Comment: No, you will need to create an array of T as well inside the method. Since you haven't shown how that method actually generate random data according to the type, it is quite difficult to explain better how you would write this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I updated my question with the function itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now all the answers (mostly) actually answer the question there are none that actually talk about using Generics instead. Now this may not fit your direct bill but can be added quite easily to resolve the issue and require no knowledge from a calling application how to understand the return values.

This is simple. Just define an overload that accepts a Generic Type (note `T`)

```
public T[] GetData<T>(int count)
{
    Type tType = typeof(T);
    //.. TODO: Generate our array.. anyway you wish..
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

So this is a basic example and callable by:

```
Factory factory = new Factory();
var arr = factory.GetData<double>(10); //returns a typed array of double
```

Now from a caller perspective we know that the data we are receivining is typed to `double` or the type they provide.

This is an alternative to your initial question. However if your array of objects will not always be the type originally requested then this will not work.

**EDIT**

To define the array is really up to how you define your objects but lets just take your initial concept and adapt it to the same above:

```
public T[] GetData<T>(int count)
{
    Type tType = typeof(T);
    //.. TODO: Generate our array.. anyway you wish..
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        list.Add((T)GetRandom(tType));
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

In the new sample we are assuming that the Method `GetRandom()` will return the Type requested. The type requested is generic based on the `typereference` (typeparam) `T`. We can get the actual type by calling `typeof(T)`. Now in this example we simply directly cast the `GetRandom()` object response (I am assuming `GetRandom()` returns a type of `object`.

**Final Edit**

As stated in the comments your can change your `object GetRandom(Type type)` to `T GetRandom<T>()`. This will allow you to generate specific types for your random. I would suggest reading up on Generics https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Now one thing that is not quickly apparent is that what you name your generic is up to you. You dont have to use `T` and you can use multiple generics in one method call, as with many methods you probably already use.

** Final Final Edit **

Just to elaborate how you could change your GetRandom method to a generic we still have to work with the type `object` its really the only one that allows for direct boxing conversion for any type. You could use the `as` keyword but that will could leave to other problems. Now the `GetRandom(Type type)` method is returning a random object of the type. As stated this is limited to a few types so lets just put together an example.

The first thing to understand is how to handle our various types. Now personally I like to define an interface. So lets define an interface for all our Random Types to inherit. As below:

```
interface IRandomTypeBuilder
{
    object GetNext();
}
```

As simple interface to return a random typed entity of with the method of `GetNext()`. This will return a typed response based on the generic parameter T.

Now some simple implementations of this interface.

```
class DoubleRandomBuilder : IRandomTypeBuilder
{
    static Random rng = new Random();        
    public object GetNext()
    {
        return rng.NextDouble() * rng.Next(0, 1000);
    }
}

class IntRandomBuilder : IRandomTypeBuilder
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    public object GetNext()
    {
        return rng.Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
    }
}

class StringRandomBuilder : IRandomTypeBuilder
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    static string aplha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public object GetNext()
    {
        string next = "";
        for (int i = rng.Next(4, 10), j = i + rng.Next(1, 10); i < j; i++)
            next += aplha[rng.Next(0, aplha.Length)];
        return next;
    }
}

class BoolRandomBuilder : IRandomTypeBuilder
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    public object GetNext()
    {
        return rng.Next(0, 2) % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

Yes these are very simple but we have 4 different types that all define the `GetNext()` method and return a random value for the type. Now we can define the `GetRandom<T>()` method.

```
public T GetRandom<T>()
{
    Type tType = typeof(T);
    IRandomTypeBuilder typeGenerator = null;
    if (tType == typeof(double))
        typeGenerator = new DoubleRandomBuilder();
    else if (tType == typeof(int))
        typeGenerator = new IntRandomBuilder();
    else if (tType == typeof(string))
        typeGenerator = new StringRandomBuilder();
    else if (tType == typeof(bool))
        typeGenerator = new BoolRandomBuilder();
    return (T)(typeGenerator == null ? default(T) : typeGenerator.GetNext());
}
```

Comment: I almost got there, could you explain more the "generate our array" part, How does it link to the list you define below?

Comment: Ok good it works!!!!!! And what if'd like to have a GetRandom() function that returns a type T exactly as GetData() does? Because I'd like to generate even single objects instead of arrays. So I could have a public GetRandom() which return a single object with random data assigned to it

Comment: I've just done what you said but declaring GetRandom() as T GetRandom<T>() break the line: list.Add((T)GetRandom(tType));

Comment: @G_G I have just done a final edit but yes you can change your GetRandom method to return a typed response. Hope this answers the question and helps you and others.

Comment: Change the line to `list.Add(GetRandom<T>())` and have remove the `Type` parameter from the GetRandom method. Sometimes it takes more work to use Generics but you are providing more transparency to your end user.

Comment: Sorry my lack of experience on that but I tried (I updated my question with the GetRandom()) to convert the GetRandom() function into a T GetRandom<T>() and it says I cannot convert int/double/DateTime/string into T

Comment: @G_G. I have added another edit.. Hope this helps someone... ;)

Comment: dude, this deserves a post on a blog!

Answer (score 6):

Use [Array.ConvertAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
values =  Array.ConvertAll(factory.GetData(typeof(double), 10), item => (double)item);
```

Example:

```
object[] input = new object[]{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
double[] output = Array.ConvertAll(input, element => (double)element); // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Note you might get `InvalidCastException` if one of the items can't be casted to double.

Answer (score 3):

You could:

```
values =  factory.GetData(typeof(double), 10).Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

Comment: This will throw 'System.InvalidCastException'

Comment: Only if the objects in the array aren't actually doubles. But we know they are because we asked for doubles.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: Here's a simple [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l8mQby) no `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: @MattBurland yes there was a problem with my example data

Answer (score 3):

If factory.GetData return an array of object of double, you can use:

```
values = factory.GetData(typeof(double), 10).Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

Comment: This will throw 'System.InvalidCastException'

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad only if `GetData` does *not* return an array of wrapped doubles. In which case there is a bug in both `GetData` and the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `GetData` *does* return doubles boxed as arrays, you can use [Cast()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) to cast all elements to double:

```
values=factory.GetData(typeof(double), 10).Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

or you can use [OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) to filter out values that are *not* double

```
values=factory.GetData(typeof(double), 10).OfType<double>().ToArray();
```

A better option though would be to rewrite `GetData` as a generic method and return a `T[]`

Comment: This will throw `'System.InvalidCastException' `

Comment: No, it won't, it will work just fine. This is within the limits imposed by the question in which it is stated that the object array contains only doubles.